# ¿Cómo puedo incrementar un numero en react native cada vez que pulse un boton?

Tags: javascript, react-native

soy nuevo en react y estoy tratando de incrementar un numero cada vez que pulse un boton **Increase**, de momento estoy usando coderbyte para practicar ejercicios y este es el código con el que estoy intentando incrementar un numero por ejemplo que empieza a contar desde 0 ¿Alguien podría ayudarme por favor se los agradecería?

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Text, View } from "react-native";

const SimpleCounter = () => {
  const [count, actualCount] = useState(0);
  let SimpleCounter = () => {
    actualCount(count + 1);
  };
  return (
    
    <View>
      <Text>button count: <span id="actualCount">0</span></Text>
      <button  action={SimpleCounter} id="mainButton">Increase</button>
    </View>
  );
};

export default SimpleCounter;
```

*Y este es el error que recibo en la consola*

```js
Warning: Invalid value for prop %s on <%s> tag. Either remove it from the element, or pass a string or number value to keep it in the DOM. For details, see https://reactjs.org/link/attribute-behavior %s
`action`
button

    at button
    at div
    at eval (webpack://react/../../react-native/node_modules/react-native-web/dist/exports/View/index.js?:56:25)
    at SimpleCounter (webpack://react/./src/App.js?:24:66)
    at div
    at eval (webpack://react/../../react-native/node_modules/react-native-web/dist/exports/View/index.js?:56:25)
    at div
    at eval (webpack://react/../../react-native/node_modules/react-native-web/dist/exports/View/index.js?:56:25)
    at AppContainer (webpack://react/../../react-native/node_modules/react-native-web/dist/exports/AppRegistry/AppContainer.js?:22:24)
```

Comment: y cual es el error?

Comment: Buenas tardes @ArcanisGK507 acabo de editar mi pregunta con el error que me da en la consola de coderbyte

Comment: y que significa ese error?

Comment: y puedo entender que hay un valor no valido pasado esto es lo que dice el error **Valor no válido para la propiedad %s en la etiqueta  Elimínelo del elemento o pase una cadena o un valor numérico para mantenerlo en el DOM** no entiendo por que no logro incrementar el valor

Comment: `button` no tiene atributo `action`... no será que necesitas es ponerle `onClick`? para que al hacerle click al botón ejecute esa accion?

Comment: Te hacen falta 2 cosas, lo primero es lo que te dijo @Pipe button no tiene atributo action tienes que utilizar `onClick={simpleCounter}` y además de eso te falta colocar la variable que captura el estado o sea `count` en el `<Text>`si no estara cambiando de estado pero nunca se va a mostrar en pantalla `<Text>button count: <span id="actualCount">{count}</span></Text>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solo tenes que hacerle algunos cambios al componente:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Text, View } from "react-native";

function SimpleCounter () {
  const [count, actualCount] = useState(0);
  let increase = () => {
    actualCount(count + 1);
  };
  return (
    
    <View>
      <Text>button count: <span id="actualCount">{count}</span></Text> /* ponemos {count} para mostrar el valor actual del contador en el span*/
      <button  onClick={increase} id="mainButton">Increase</button> /* al activarse el evento click se llama a la funcion y se incrementa el contador */
    </View>
  );
};

export default SimpleCounter;
```

no soy experto en React pero eso deberia funcionar, saludos.

Comment: Si, funciona perfecto de hecho estaba editando el código en [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/old-leaf-y3zb5l?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: si, efectivamente funciona @ElFuturo y una llamada onClick era lo que le faltaba muchas gracias a todos